# Uploading Text on firebase realtime database android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am uploading text and images on the firebase database, however, only the images get uploaded and the texts fail to upload. Following that the app crashes. I am using the onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) method.

I will be using Edittexts to get user input

**Below is the code for my MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declarations
    Button btnbrowse, btnupload;
    EditText txtdata, txtdata1, txtdata2;
    ImageView imgview;
    Uri FilePathUri;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    int Image_Request_Code = 7;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Images");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Images");
        btnbrowse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnbrowse);
        btnupload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
        txtdata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdata);
        txtdata1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdata1);
        txtdata2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdata2);
        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);// context name as per your project name

        btnbrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), Image_Request_Code);
            }
        });

        btnupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //call the upload method
                UploadImage();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            FilePathUri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
                imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

    }

    public void UploadImage() {

        if (FilePathUri != null) {

            progressDialog.setTitle("Image is uploading");
            progressDialog.show();
            StorageReference storageReference2 = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." +
                    GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));

            storageReference2.putFile(FilePathUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    String TempImageName = txtdata.getText().toString().trim();
                    String TempImageName1 = txtdata1.getText().toString().trim();
                    String TempImageName2 = txtdata2.getText().toString().trim();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stuff Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    Uploadinfo imageUploadInfo = new Uploadinfo(TempImageName, TempImageName1, TempImageName2, taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString());
                    String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                    databaseReference.push().getKey();
                    databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                }
            });
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Select Image or Add Image Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the java model code**

```
public class Uploadinfo {

    public String TempImageName;
    public String TempImageName1;
    public String TempImageName2;
    public String imageURL;

    public Uploadinfo(){

    }

    public Uploadinfo(String name, String name1, String name2, String url){

        this.TempImageName = name;
        this.TempImageName1 = name1;
        this.TempImageName2 = name2;
        this.imageURL = url;
    }

    public String getTempImageName() {
        return TempImageName;
    }

    public String getTempImageName1() {
        return TempImageName1;
    }

    public String getTempImageName2() {
        return TempImageName2;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem , Thanks